# exit on error + echo doesnt work together

Tags: bash

I'm trying to add a meaningful error message to errors in my script, and exit at the 1st exit.

I tried `<*errornous_command_returning_non_zero_value*> || (err=$? && echo $LINENO && exit $err)`

For some reason that I don't understand, the line is echoed, but the exit is not executed and the script continues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only exit the subshell `( )` but not the actual shell.

You can use `{ }` instead of a subshell `( )` to group your commands. Example:

```
false || { err=$?; echo msg; exit $err; }
```

Comment: Additional improvement: Don't use `&&`, because you don't really want each of those commands to execute conditionally upon success of the previous one. Just use `;`.

Comment: @ClsForCookies No. Bash requires it. Without the last `;` the closing `}` would be interpreted as an argument.